# How to return 5 number summary as an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a program that established methods for mean, med, mode, q1, q3, max and min. 
the last method should return a 5 number summary(min, q1, med, q3, max) as an array. Since I already have methods established and working properly for all of these I need a simple way to incorporate all these values into a new method and return as an array. 
I tried this

```
public static int calcNumsum(int[] a) { 
  int min; 
  int max; 
  int q1; 
  int q3; 
  int med;
  int[] vals = new int[5];
  vals[1] = min; 
  vals [2] = q1; 
  vals [3] = med; 
  vals [4] = q3; 
  vals [5] = max; 
  return vals;
```

it gave me back a compiling error 
int[] cannot be converted to int. 
any suggestions on how to fix this or a better way to return the array?

Answer (score 1):

`int[][][][][]` is a 5 dimensional array, not a one dimensional array with 5 elements.

```
int[] vals = new int[5];  // this has 5 elements
// ... assign values like vals[0] = whoever etc
return vals;
```

Or, shorthand

```
return new int[]{ val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 };
```

edit: From comments

```
public static int calcNumsum(int[] a) {
    int min; int max; int q1; int q3; int med; int[] vals = new int[5];
    vals[1] = min; vals [2] = q1; vals [3] = med; vals [4] = q3; vals [5] = max;
    return vals;
}
```

- Declared method type is `int`, but you are returning an `int[]`
- All of the `int` variables you delcared are uninitialized, so your returned array will always be `{0,0,0,0,0}` as it is now
- `vals[5]` is out of range of your array, array indexing starts at 0
- Taking the parameter `a` but not using it at all?

Judging by your initial post, you want to take all 5 values and return the array of them all? If that is the case, you can use the cheapo variable number of arguments trick.

```
public static int[] toArray(int... vals) {
    return vals;
}
```

and call it like

```
int[] theVals = toArray(min, q1, med, q3, max);
// theVals[0] = min, theVals[1] = q1, etc
```

Comment: it is still spitting back the error cannot convert int[] to int

Comment: Presumably you're declaring something as `int` instead of `int[]`, either the  method type or the value you are trying to assign it to.

Comment: Are your established methods returning an array or integers?

Comment: There's lots of things wrong there. I will edit my post.

Comment: Ok I posted the whole method of what i have so far. it is still throwing back the compiling error int [] cannot be converted to int. if i change `public static int` to `public static int[]` it tells me I need variable declaration.

Comment: I tried that. I need to incorporate the variable a some how because it holds my previous array and all the values.

Comment: So `a` already has all the values you want, why do you need to make an array of the values you want?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your array incorrectly.

```
int[] numSum = new int[]{min,q1,med,q3,max};
```

Try reading this post to understand declaring arrays better: [How do I declare and initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the input?
2. Do you need to return 5 arrays or just 5 values?

Assuming that these answers are obvious and you need 5-dimensional array and not 5 values and nested list-of-lists are not an option, this is not possible directly in java. Java stores n-dimensional array as an one-dimensional array and you can use that. So, effectively, you can create an one dimensional array along with column size and manipulate the values as you want.

---

As per the changed question, you are returning int[] for a method which is defined to return int.

Change

```
public static int calcNumsum(int[] a)
```

to

```
public static int[] calcNumsum(int[] a)
```

Comment: the inputs are in previous methods that have already been accounted for.

Comment: I have updated my answer as per updated question. It should fix your problem.